# Crossing sea border between Montenegro and Croatia

Tags: local-customs, sea-travel, croatia, montenegro, dubrovnik

I'm going to rent sailing yacht in Montenegro and visit some towns on south coast (till Dubrovnik) of Croatia. And then come back to Montenegro.

What custom procedures I have to do when leaving Montenegro and entering Croatia, and when coming back? When and where it is better to do it?

Comment: Do you have a cruising guide for the area?

Comment: @DJClayworth, no I have not. And I've never crossed the sea border. I'm interesting in details.

Comment: A cruising guide will give you details of customs procedures, legal ports of entry, as well as marinas and anchorages. I don't have any recommendations, never having been to the area, but a search turns up these guides. http://www.bookharbour.com/?p=catalog&mode=search&search_str=montenegro A reputable yacht rental will probably give you this information too. They don't want their boat seized by customs any more than you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Check-out from Montenegro**

I have checked-out in Porto Montenegro. There is comfortable service: marina crew will help you with all procedure (for free, if you stay a night here). All activities ~ 1 hour.

It's possible to do all procedures in Zelenika.

**Check-in in Croatia**

There are customs docks in Cavtat town, nice small town. It takes 40 minutes and 100 Kn (~20$).

Alternative: marina Gruz near Dubrovnik.